# A complex 4×4 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $4×4$ complex matrix s.t. $Rank(A)=2$ and $A^3=A^2\ne 0$. If $A$ is not diagonalizable then how to prove the following?

**(a)** The characteristic polynomial is $x^4-x^3$

**(b)** There exists a vector $v$ s.t. $Av\ne 0$ but $A^2v=0$.

*My try:* $x^2(x-1)$ is annihilating polynomial so minimal polynomial will be either $x^2(x-1)$ or $x(x-1)$. Now, I am stuck how to reject one of these? I think the second one has to be rejected but why? And then why $x^2(x-1)^2$ cann't be the characteristic polynomial?
Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the annihilating polynomial were $x(x-1)$, its roots would be simple and the endomorphism would be diegonalisable. Hence the minimal polynomial is $x^2(x-1)$.

Furthermore, $\ker A\varsubsetneq \ker A^2$, and $\dim \ker A=2$, since $\operatorname{rank}A=2$. As there is another eigenvalue,  $\dim\ker A^2= 3$, so that $\dim\ker(A-I)=1$, which implies the characteristic polynomial is $x^3(x-1)$.